# prove x/(x^2 + 1) is continuous at x = 0 using the definition of continuity

Tags: continuity

My solution is as follow.

[image]

Can anyone tell if my calculation is correct.

Comment: makes sense to me, but i don't understand what it has to do with triangle inequality, it is obvious that $\left|x^2+1\right| \ge \left| x^2 \right|$

Comment: did you mean I will take x^2<epsilon?

Comment: Writing $\left|\frac x{x^2+1}\right|\leq\frac 1{|x|}$ does not help. You need to write it as $\left|\frac x{x^2+1}\right|\leq |x|$, using $x^2+1\geq 1$.